# Raster resolution stuck at 96dpi in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, dpi

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.5.

I have a high resolution raster I've downloaded from a state run imagery site, sid format.  I'm trying to export it to a pdf using the native resolution.  The dpi is seems to be locked at 96dpi, see capture below.  The resulting pdf is not nearly as high resolution as the actual raster, I can put it side by side with the map view and clearly see the quality difference.

I understand the ESRI basemaps lock themselves at 96dpi, but this is just an unrestricted 3rd party raster.  In ArcMap for this imagery source all I had to do to get the best resolution is set the dpi to 350.

Why can't I do that with ArcGIS Pro?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've posted a screenshot of the Raster Resample option (called Output Image Quality) in ArcMap.  There's also a resolution option on the PAGE export that would allow you to get a specific dots per inch in your output.

If you're doing a MAP VIEW export, you don't really have an "inch" with which to set DPI. In ArcMap some math was done to "simulate" a DPI based on the aspect ratio of the map view you have open, and then squeeze that into the dpi you selected as an export, to get your result.

In ArcGIS Pro, the effective resolution is determined by the number of pixels in each axis.  The user can input the number of pixels they want in X and Y axes, and see a preview of the result of that aspect ratio, so they know what extent they're getting.  These parameters were a read-only field in the ArcMap export experience, FWIW.

Back to your workflow: 
If what you want is an export at "native" resolution, you can just look at the number of pixels in each axis in your raster (for instance by looking at the Source properties in the raster layer) and type in those values for X and Y axes in the export dialog, to get a "native" resolution export to a PDF.

Give it a try, and let know if that works for your workflow.

Comment: Great!  Glad to hear it.